# How to create vectors on the fly with dynamic vector names in the java programming language?

Tags: java

I have a data file. I am reading chunk by chunk of the data file. The data file has delimiters for each chunk. I do not know how big the data file will be. I do not know how many chunks are in the data file. I need a vector created for the data in each chunk. I would like the vectors named something like vector0, vector1, vector2, etc. How do I create an unknown number of vectors with such a naming convention

Comment: When did vectors get a `name` property? You should really make more efford in explaining your problem.

Comment: Ok. I have a data file. I am reading chunk by chunk of the data file. The data file has delimiters for each chunk. I do not know how big the data file will be. I do not know how many chunks are in the data file. I need a vector created for the data in each chunk. I would like the vectors named something like vector0, vector1, vector2, etc. How do I create an unknown number of vectors with such a naming convention.

Comment: Simply replace the array mentioned in the answers in the dupe with a `List`, e.g. `ArrayList`...

Comment: Thank you for all your help.